# Language change on button click

Tags: android

stucked with one problem that in my application i have one button which is having text SPANISH on it. On the click of this button i want to change the whole application to Spanish language.

```
Locale mLocale = new Locale("es");
    Locale.setDefault(mLocale); 
    Configuration config = getBaseContext().getResources().getConfiguration(); 
    if (!config.locale.equals(mLocale)) 
    { 
        config.locale = mLocale; 
        getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, null); 
    }
```

I also have created two separate Strings.xml file. but not got success.
I want to change the application language on button click.

Thanks

Comment: do you have a String.xml in res/values and one in res/values-es ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you have to call  `setContentView()`  after you change the locale